# Installing Bootcamp 5.1 on Windows 8.1

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

While trying to run Bootcamp 5.1 on Windows 8.1 (which is claimed to be supported here: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720), I am getting the error message "Boot Camp requires that your computer is running Windows 7".

Is there something I am doing wrong?  How do get the proper drivers installed on my Boot Camp install of Windows 8.1 on my Mid-2011 Macbook Air?

Comment: Is your mac running 10.9 mavericks?

Comment: Yes, it is running Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem.. and this might be the solution.

I use MacBook Pro late 2011 and installed Windows 8.1.

(prepare your USB min. 4GB)

1. ensure you download the Windows support software from Apple Bootcamp.
2. you will get Windows support folder in the USB.
3. restart to Windows
4. open your USB file there..
5. you will find setup.exe
6. right click on your setup.exe
7. go to compability tab
8. check the box of Run this program in compability mode for (and change the list to Windows 8)
9. apply
10. right click again on setup.exe
11. run as administrator
12. and click. run the program without getting help.
13. installing
14. restart
15. and voila... everything works.